# Getting 404 error while accessing the DNN Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

I have DNN 8 installed on my local machine (Windows 10). I am trying to create a simple API by following the steps as in [Ryan Gunn's blog](https://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/dotnetnuke-webapi-helloworld-example-part-one/comment-page-1/). When I try to access the API, I am able to get a response from the API.

I have another remote server (Windows Server) which too has DNN 8 in it. I am following the same steps as in the blog. However, every time I access the API in the server, I am getting a 404 error.

Is there anything I'm missing or a configuration setting incorrect on the server?

**Update:**
The code is exactly the same as in the blog on both machines.

The GET Url in my local machine is - http://dnndev.me/DesktopModules/DataExchange/API/Example/HelloWorld
and in the server it is - http://{serverwebsiteurl}/DesktopModules/DataExchange/API/Example/HelloWorld.

I have a `ExampleController` class and within that below GET method is present:

```
[DnnAuthorize()]
[HttpGet()]
public HttpResponseMessage HelloWorld()
{
    try
    {
        string helloWorld = "Hello World!";
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, helloWorld);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        //Log to DotNetNuke and reply with Error
        //Exceptions.LogException(ex);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Upgrade, building/learning on DNN 8 is many years out of date
2. Could you include your code?
3. Could you show your GET or POST URL?

Comment: @Accuraty-Jeremy I have added the code. The issue is I am getting the response from the API in my local machine but I am getting a 404 error in the server.

Comment: What are your settings for portal alias mapping modes, and is SSL enabled/enforced?

Comment: @MitchelSellers The portal alias mapping is set to CANONICALURL and SSL is not enabled/not enforced.